# Notification doesn't show up if only large icon is set

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to add a large icon to my notification, but when I run the app, the notification doesn't show up.

When I change to small icon, it works but icon is too small.

Below is my code, any help where it is wrong?

```
Bitmap rawBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                                     R.drawable.ic_launcher);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setLargeIcon(rawBitmap)
    .setContentTitle("Alert")
    .setContentText("CITRUS PUNCH Minute Maid expired");
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: try to add both SetStyle and SetPriorityas as the following :

  .SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message.Long_Message))   
  .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [notification guide list of required fields](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required), you **must** set a small icon via the [setSmallIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)) method. Generally, this icon looks like your application icon, although entirely as white over a transparent background per the [notification iconography guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification): tools such as the [Notification Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) may help in building an appropriate small icon.

On Android 5.0+ devices, you can use [setColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)) to set a branded background color for behind your small icon.

Large icons are *not* meant for branding purposes - instead, they should be used to [make it personal](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#MakeItPersonal) and be an image associated with the sender of the notification (i.e., a profile picture) or additional information to convey the meaning of the notification.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and ended up not using the large icon because of the same error. Do you mean to say that the large icon is not meant be used for just showing a notification?

Comment: Right, you're much better off not using a large icon if all you are going use it for is your launcher icon: that will almost never look quite right due to how notifications are displayed

Comment: Thanks this will stop a lot of waste of time in trying to make the large icon work:-)